# Django-Admin : Override add-URL of the Foreign Key Auto-Complete "add" button / + green cross

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin

Is there a simple way of overriding/pass a parameter to the popup url automatically created by `django-admin` built-in autocomplete/select2 widget to create a new foreign key object? This url is embedded in the green cross (see picture).
I didn't come across any well described solutions.

So the default url is pointing towards `admin/app/model/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1` but I would like to add a parameter `admin/app/model/add/?_to_field=id&_popup=1&field_1=100` in order to pre-populate some fieds on the popup add_view.

Any leads?

[image: add foreign key django admin]

As per Maxim's answer :

```
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "clinical_exam":
        widget = super(ConsultationAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs).widget
        widget.template_name = 'admin/related_widget_wrapper_with_id.html'
        widget.attrs.update({'your_parameter': 'you can use it after in template'})
        print(db_field)
        return db_field.formfield(widget=widget)
    return super(ConsultationAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

'change + -' this is a result of render `RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper`
from `django.contrib.admin.widgets`

You can change attributes of this widget, but it is a little bit complicated.

in `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield`:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
    widget = super.formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs).widget 
    if isinstance(widget, RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
        old_context = widget.get_context
        widget.get_context = my_function(widget.get_context, *args, **kwargs)
```

my function is a decorator for old function:

```
def my_function(func, *initargs, **initkwargs):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        context = func(*args, **kwargs)
        your_keys_vals_to_add_in_url = 'something in form key=val&'
        context['url_params'] = f'{context['url_params']}&{your_keys_vals_to_add_in_url}'
        return context
    return wrapped
```

Other possibility is - to change `template related_widget_wrapper.html`
from `django.admin.contrib.templates.admin.widgets`
You can hardcoded your values there.

in `ModelAdmin.formfield_for_dbfield`:

```
def formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
    widget = super.formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs).widget
    if isinstance(widget, RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper):
        widget.template_name = 'path/to/your_overriden_related_widget_wrapper.html'
        widget.attrs.update('your_parameter' : 'you can use it after in template')  # this is not work right now in django
```

and after it in own template:

```
# example for change link
# this is not work right now in django
<a ... data-href-template="{{ change_related_template_url }}?{{ url_params }}&{{ attr.your_parameter|dafault:'' }}" .. >
```

The last part not works in Django right now. I made an issue in Django project about this possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you access `your_parameter` with your second option in the overriden  template. Tried :     {{ rendered_widget }}
    `{{ rendered_widget.field }}
    {{ rendered_widget.field.your_parameter }}
    {{ rendered_widget.field.your_parameter }}
    {{ field.field.widget.attrs }}
    {{ widget.attrs.your_parameter }}
    {{ rendered_widget.attrs }}
    {{ formfield.widget.attrs.your_parameter }}` but none of them work to access the value. See the form_function in the initial post.

Comment: {{ attrs.your_parametr }}

Comment: i add in answer

Comment: I tried this one already. It remains empty. But that's surprising given the widget received the new template and I can modify it properly. It's like atts is not passed to the template.

Comment: you are damned right! Probably you find a bug in django! the first part works. The own template also works.